# What is the different between expert and Comfortable Working Knowledge?

Tags: applications

During my applying to an investment bank, there is two field under the **Technology Skills**: **Expert** and **Comfortable Working Knowledge**.
What is the difference between the two?

Can someone give an **sample** about the two fields?

Comment: Expert would mean you can troubleshoot, make stuff with it etc,. Working knowledge means you can use it comfortably I would think

Comment: @Kilisi can give an specific example to illustrate?

Comment: Expert = I can build a server from scratch, versus Comfortable working knowledge =  I can administer a server if nothing too out of the ordinary happens

Comment: Depends on kind of technology. Say its an Excel - Working Knowledge = You can work on excel, know the basic functions, formatting Expert= You can write macros, automate excel functions etc

Comment: About 500% and two decades.

Comment: CWK = understands everything when it works right:  Expert: understands everything that can go wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: @RichardU - That is succinct brilliance bordering on poetry.

Answer (score 5):

Expert = Vast experience to the degree that others could be instructed (if the expert has teaching ability)

CWK = Can work without supervision, but would quickly be 'found out' as an instructor

Comment: @Kilisi: I agree that it doesn't imply teaching ability, as many experts are quite useless instructors. The point is that they could instruct others based on their experience, whereas a CWK probably cannot

Comment: Some level of teaching ability is implied. If people come to you on a subject instead of going to Google, you are an expert. On the other hand, if you have amazing knowledge but can't articulate it to others, then you will sadly not be recognized as an expert.

Answer (score 1):

Common Working Knowledge - can handle most of what would come up in the average working day in that field. That is to say someone who can handle the job without training (i.e. not a junior or entry level person) other than company specific training. They tend to favor breadth of knowledge over depth

Expert - the person everyone goes to when things go wrong or when there is a very obscure issue. They may not know everything about what they are expert in (although their knowledge is deep), but they know exactly where to go to get the knowledge when something obscure happens. They tend to favor depth of knowledge over breadth (but don't ignore breadth). They could write the book on the chosen technology.